# Can't connect Azure Table Storage to PowerBI (415) Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: azure-storage, powerbi, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage, http-status-code-415

I'm getting the error below while connecting to Azure Table Storage,

Details:

> Blockquote "AzureTables: Request failed: The remote server returned an error:
>
> (415) Unsupported Media Type. (None of the provided media types are
> supported)

The one thing I noticed is that if I fill up only the account name it will automatically add the rest of the url which is `".table.core.windows.net"` where in the portal its `table.cosmosdb.azure.com`.

With `core.windows.net` Im getting err `"AzureTables: Request failed: The remote name could not be resolved"`. But it might messing up some headers while using `table.cosmosdb.azure.com`

Please advise.

Thank you.
m

Comment: Resolution of that was that I switched to Azure Table Storage with storage account not a Cosmos DB one.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to connect to your azure table storage/CosmosDB account using powerBi using the following link structure: `https://STORAGEACCOUNTNAME.table.core.windows.net/` , or `https://yourcosmosdbname.documents.azure.com:443/`  for cosmosdb

You can get the correct link by going to Portal > go to Storage accounts > Click on Tables/CosmosDB > You'll find the table link you would like to link to powerbi > remove the last table name after "/", then use it to connect in powerbi, it will later allow you to select the specific table in powerBI:

These are screenshots from testing for CosmosDB:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Errors 415**:
When it comes to these errors, they can be caused by cache, which can be flushed by going to:

In Power BI Desktop: Go to "File"  and select "Options". Under "Data Load" you have the option to clear the cache. After doing this you can use "Get Data" and "OData-feed" as normal and the URL won't return the 415 error

Check the following [link](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Integrations-with-Files-and/Power-BI-desktop-gives-error-415-Unsupported-Media-Type-with/m-p/27706#M3222) for additional suggestions:

Comment: The thing is that Im using Azure Cosmos DB account and Azure Table. Its called Azure Table API under cosmosDB. Not sure why it has the same name if its under two different accounts. However, Ive tried connect thru Cosmos DB in PBI but Im getting "We coudlnt authenticate with the credentials provided." Im just copying my endpoint and primary key.

Comment: I just tried with CosmosDB and it worked as well, I tried it using PowerBI Desktop, the connection with CosmosDB is in preview, but I just connected a test account. Let me know if you'd like me to change the above screenshots with the CosmosDB ones.

Comment: @mairo0820 would you like me to go ahead and do the above? Also, are using the Desktop powerBI option ?

Comment: sure go ahead. Have you ever experienced 415?  Thanks!

Comment: @mairo0820 I edited the answer to address the CosmosDB and the 415 errors

Comment: I also tried test account and that works fine. My crendetials does not. Im going to switch to Table storage instead cause this CosmosDB with Table API is still in Preview.

Comment: Sounds good, i actually used the keys for the cosmos db which worked for me. It should work for you as well unless the key was revoked. Please upvote or mark as answer if the post was helpful to you, in order to help future community members with the same question.

Comment: @mairo0820 Was the new solution helpful to your question ?

Comment: I was able to do those steps before. The problem was with CosmosDB Table API what I eventually removed and went with Azure Table Storage account. Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation points to upvote your comment. Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to upvote or mark as an answer the actual answer(not the comments)

Answer (score 0):

Not clear how you consume the table service API, but here is the solution that worked for me for React SPA and fetch api.

Request header must contain:

`"Content-Type":"application/json"`

It was failing for me with single quotes, and worked with **double**.